# Como validar un cursor vacio postgreSql

Tags: postgresql

Como validar si el siguiente cursor viene vacío,

```
DECLARE

validate  TEXT;

c_story_smsg_ini CURSOR FOR
    select smsg_smsg, smsg_stms from gms_tstory_smsg
    where smsg_stms in ('SMSG_STMS_INI')   
    and smsg_story = p_story_story
    ;
```

Ejemplo:

```
BEGIN
     FOR i IN c_story_smsg_ini 
     LOOP

           IF (c_story_smsg_ini IS NOT NULL) THEN

                validate := 'Data';

           ELSE

                validate := 'No_Data'

           END IF;

     END LOOP;
END;
```

Se quiere validar que si el cursor esta vacío, entonces se guarde un mensaje de que viene vacío, pero como el cursor ya esta vacío se salta el FOR y no lo valida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es que le pones la condición de salida del loop asociada a que no encuentre más registros. De paso, te falta abrir el cursor.

```
declare
current_row   record;
c_story_smsg_ini cursor blahblah
...

begin
open c_story_smsg_ini;
    
   loop
    -- carga fila en record
      fetch c_story_smsg_ini into current_row;
    -- sale del loop cuando no encuentre siguiente registro
      exit when not found;

    -- haces cosas con la fila row, etc
    ...

   end loop;
  
   -- cerrar cursor
close c_story_smsg_ini;
...
```